# Remove list style decoration of a joomla menu

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to remove the text decorations of a Joomla menu.

The menu is a simple html list and I have tried to set  `text-decoration` to 'list-style', 'list-style-type' and `text-decoration-line` to none. But nothing works.

I have set the general `li` and `ul` selectors also as the specific class/id.

```
ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: outside none none;
      text-decoration-line: none;
}

li{
      list-style-type: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: outside none none;
      text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

[image: joomla menu]

***I need to remove the marker before the item, and the white line under the text.***

### **update:**

I fixed the line under the text by adding:

```
      border-bottom: none;
```

Comment: What do firebug or dev tools tell you about where this is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe background or list-style-image ist used? Try this:

```
ul, ul li {
    background-image:none;
    list-style-image:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
li {
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: url(data:0); // FOR IE
}
```

This works better for *Internet Explorer 11*:

```
li {
list-style-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
}
```